# How to create my own gauss kernel?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, javacv

can someone tell me how i can create my own gauss-kernel?
In the paper [Frequency-tuned Salient Region Detection (Section 4.2)](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~strider/publications/SaliencyCVPR09.pdf) they use a DoG-Bandpass filter. I don't know how to implement this in OpenCV/JavaCV.
The Kernel for the DoG is called: 1/16[1; 4; 6; 4; 1]. Can someone explain how to set those kernels ?

//EDIT:
in time, i've set up my DoG Filter with:

```java
double sigma_small = Math.PI/2.75; 
double sigma_large = DOUBLE.POSITIVE_INFINITY; 
IplImage gaussL= cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
IplImage gaussS= cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
cvSmooth(input, gaussL, CV_GAUSSIAN, kernel_size,kernel_size, sigma_small, sigma_small);
cvSmooth(input, gaussS,CV_GAUSSIAN, kernel_size,kernel_size, sigma_large, sigma_large); //eq. to 0
```

But i thought it's the wrong kernel. Or i did something wrong.
greetings,
destiny

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kernel is just cv::Mat

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gauss#getgaussiankernel

As documentation says you should create Mat kernel you want and:

```
"generated kernels can be passed to sepFilter2D() or to createSeparableLinearFilter()"
```

I haven't tested it but should work.

You can also apply operation based on kernel by hand. It is not hard.

Comment: google for some references of implementing Gaussian Filter http://rastergrid.com/blog/2010/09/efficient-gaussian-blur-with-linear-sampling/ http://www.librow.com/articles/article-9 http://lodev.org/cgtutor/filtering.html I just scrolled this sites. You can propably find better references.